# jQuery = Excecute a function every x Seconds while function return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops, do-while

Thanks for the attention, and sorry form my very bad english.

I have a nice function using jQuery:

```
function(){
    //do something
    if(certain conditions){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The function work nice... But I need to execute it every X seconds, while the function returns false. If the function returns true, the loop must be stopped.

I have not idea how to do that... Can you help me? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

you could use an setInterval combined with clearInterval.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(certain conditions)
    {
        // this will prevent the function from running again
        clearInterval(interval); 
        return true;
    }

    return false;
},1000); // 1000 ms or, 1 sec
```

Comment: And how the unknown logic (which is badly described from the OP's question) will use the returned value?

Comment: @Ele that's a great question.  He didn't actually say he needed to use the returned value, just that the function had to stop being called when it would return true.

Comment: @Ele, also, it's not my responsibility to show him how to use a return value.  What would I do, instead of returning the value I would set some variable to either true or false, then check that variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the good old `window.setInterval()`:

```
var interval = 500;
function callback(){
  //your function call here
  var result = yourFunction();
  //check if we need to clear the timeout
  if(result == true){
      clearTimeout(handle);
  }
}
var handle = setInterval(callback, interval)
```

Here's a snippet.

```js
var interval = 500;
function callback(){
 //your function call here
  var result = yourFunction();
  //check if we need to clear the timeout
  if(result == true){
    clearTimeout(handle);
  }
}
var handle = setInterval(callback, interval)

function yourFunction(){
  document.write(new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
  if(Math.random() > 0.2){return false}
  else return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for the [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function.

```js
function yourFunction(){
    // do your task
    if(1 == 1 /* the condition to make the loop continue*/){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function loop(){

  if(yourFunction()){
      window.setTimeout(loop, 1000);
  }
}

loop();
```

Comment: @CalvinNunes Just one of a plethora of articles answering "why not use setInterval" https://dev.to/akanksha_9560/why-not-to-use-setinterval--2na9

Comment: nice to know, didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: This will run forever

Comment: No, just as long as yourFunction returns true.

Comment: Ok, yeah I see it now, sorry for that. 
I am trying to UNDO the -1 but it's locked for some reason, so... unless you edit the answer, It cannot be undone :(

Comment: It's updated...